# Bit-wise hack for updating a value when it is 0

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Going through some legacy C++ code. At a lot of places I see the pattern:

```
if (theFloatValue == 0) theFloatValue = anotherFloatArray[4];
```

Is there a bit manipulation hack that can help me write a branchless code for the same?

The code in itself is fine and works without any issue.

---

Not trying premature optimization. Only asking out of curiosity after seeing the ubiquity of this code pattern.

Comment: Do you know if there is actually a branch in the assembly?  The optimizer might already do what you want.

Comment: Branchless code will always call the function, is that what you want and you mean by optimization?

Comment: This could be optimized into a conditional branch instruction and assignment.  Set the optimization and look at the assembly language generated by your compiler.

Comment: Not quite branchless, but maybe: `theFloatValue = theFloatValue? theFloatValue : ValueFromXyzFunctionCall();`

Comment: There are two separate branching operations here. One is the jump/goto associated with the if/then statement. The other is the function call. Without knowing what that function does, it's hard to say whether that branch can be eliminated.

Comment: @NathanOliver: My C++ knowledge is 0. I'll find a way to look at the optimizer code and add in the question.

Comment: @Bron: What if instead of method call, there is some actual value like `anotherFloatArray[index]`?

Comment: There's a general naive technique to reduce and multiply: `theFloatValue = !theFloatValue * anotherFloatArray[4];`. That doesn't mean such a thing would perform well.

Comment: @chris: That is actually a valid answer. I’m not looking to make the code faster or anything, as I already said.

Comment: As I recall, there are condition-code-controlled variants on some (all?) common instructions in ARM assembly.  So a branchless version of your code is `tst theFloatValue` ... `movZ theFloatValue, anotherFloatArray[4]`.  In other words, the `mov` is only executed if the `Z` flag is set (otherwise it's a `NOP`).  Of course, this requires that the processor can test and move _float_ values; if floats are larger than what the CPU can manipulate with registers, then you're going to have more stuff going on anyway.

Comment: Actually, mine might not work as well as hoped what with the number being a `float`. I didn't realize that, as I'm used to seeing this tricks applied to integers. Then again, the code in the question checks against 0 without an epsilon or anything, and doesn't seem to even consider -0. In any case, the `!` could be replaced with `!(... == 0)` I guess.

Comment: @DaveM.That's very neat. According to some sources x86 supports that instruction too. Edit: Nevermind, apparently in x86 the instruction movz does a completely different thing.

Comment: @DaveM. Ah, but it has `cmovz`and other `cmov*` variants that have conditional move, so yeah I guess this kind of optimization works for x86 too.

Comment: @chris: An answer clicked me suddenly. I verified it and was about to post as self answer. Just then I saw that it was same as your answer. But, I also saw that there is a slight mistake in your answer. It should be: `theFloatValue  += !theFloatValue * anotherFloatArray[4];`

Comment: @displayName, Good point, I guess I was thinking to set it to either `anotherFloatArray[4]` or `0` instead of setting it only on one branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that using some math:

x is the value you want to manipulate, y is the value you want x to be when its 0.

**Case #1**

```
x = 0
=> !x = 1
=> !x * y = y
=> (!x * y) + x = (!x * y) = y
```

**Case #2**

```
x != 0
=> !x = 0
=> !x * y = 0
=> (!x * y) + x = 0 + x = x
```

**Result**

`x = (!x * y) + x` is what you need

Comment: Further shortened to ‘x += !x * y’

Answer (score 2):

If you can replace `theFloatValue` by an array, the following <strike>should</strike>[1] be branchless:

```
float theFloatValue[2];  // index 0: the old value, index 1: dummy
...
theFloatValue[theFloatValue[0] != 0] = anotherFloatArray[4]; // see [2]
```

`theFloatValue[0]` is now the former `theFloatValue`. The index 1 is used as an alternative location to place the result when it is not needed.

<sup>As always: This has to be tested if it makes an improvement or not.</sup>

---

[1] It's probably not branchless as [Matteo Italia commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496284/bit-wise-hack-for-updating-a-value-when-it-is-0/46496478#comment79947953_46496478).

[2] With a `NaN` value, the calculation of the index `theFloatValue[0] != 0` does not behave the same as the original from the question, as [chris commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496284/bit-wise-hack-for-updating-a-value-when-it-is-0/46496478#comment79948090_46496478). With `!(theFloatValue[0] == 0)`, this can be avoided, because the equality check on the `float` is the same. The 'not' is perfored on the `bool`.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I wonder if it's really relevant to do this or leave the branch optimization to the optimizer. I guess some benchmarking will tell.

Comment: Yep. Any optimizing attempt should be tested.

Comment: I mean, if you know your assembly, doing it with `if` means there's literally only 1 `mov` instruction to be jumped, as far as I know. The whole thing is already in the CPU cache anyway, it's not like you are actually rebranching.

Comment: It's not like if there's no `if` there's no branch... stuff like `theFloatValue[0] != 0` often becomes a branch (in the minimal case, [it's a branch at every optimization level on gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/BfjZ9R)).

Comment: Worth noting that unless I'm mistaken, this will not work the same for NaN because `NaN == 0` is false, but `NaN != 0` is also false. That could be fixed by matching the original condition: `!(theFloatValue[0] == 0)`

Comment: I think you're both correct, @MatteoItalia and chris. I'll edit that in.

Comment: @Bob__: Is there a good tutorial I can follow to understand the compiler explorer output?

Comment: @displayName Well, that would be [assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), but what I was (poorly) trying to illustrate, is maybe better shown [here](http://quick-bench.com/BvFo51wnKGE0WjkQiiQ4sHxPe4U) and [here](http://quick-bench.com/3FfCfyx8eg2sLJmvGe1GOF2FDy0). Many clever optimizations don't survive the optimizers.